# Adding dependencies in Hackerrank

Tags: java

I was solving a question on **Hackerrank** where I had to hit an API which was returning **Json**, then I had to map into Object. I had used Libraries like Gson and ObjectMapper to solve the question but the Hackerank IDE was not able to resolve Gson and ObjectMapper libraries even after adding gson and Object mapper libraries in import section. Is there any way to add dependencies in Hackerrank IDE and successfully submit it?

Comment: Sorry Cannot provide the exact question link as this question was asked to me in an Online test.

Comment: you most probably are not expected to use external libraries on such sites... (I would never allow including such libraries in any similar site, to start just because of security)

Answer (score 2):

According to the HackerRank Environment documentation, the following libraries are available:

TestNG, **JSON Simple**, Tagsoup, **Google/Gson**, HTTPCore, HTTPClient, XMLResolver, Jing, JUnit, Hamcrest, Commons Lang3, Commons Logging.

Source: https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500002392722-Execution-Environment.  (Click on "Coding and Database" and scroll to the Java information ...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not allowed to use libraries or frameworks in these challenges. The idea is to check how **you** would solve the problem, not the developer of a library. That's why these lessons are so challenging. Back to the roots: Use just the *Java API* itself to pass!